# jQuery, using ! to say "not selected"

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

Is it possible to do something like this to check if radio form is unchecked:

```
if !($(this).find("input:checked")) {}
```

what would be the correct syntax?

Comment: You mean, you want to verify all `<input type="radio">` as descendents of `this` are all unchecked?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(this).find("input:not(:checked)")
```

Comment: For future searchers, syntax also works with `option:not(:selected)`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead bc `.find` returns an array of DOM elements:

```
if ($(this).find("input:checked").length == 0) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.is` for boolean test

```
if (!$(this).find('input').is(':checked')) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'll want that `!` inside the conditional check:

```
if (!$(this).find("input:checked")) {}
```

Second of all, the [.find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method returns a jQuery object, so even if it found nothing, it will still be truthy.

What you'll probably want to check is the length of the jQuery object:

```
if (!$(this).find("input:checked").length) {}
```

If there are no elements, then etc etc etc

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're searching a parent element (e.g. a form) to see if you can find descendant checkboxes that are checked.

You want something like this:

```
if (!$(this).find('input:radio:checked').length) {
```

The condition passes if there are no descendant radio input elements that are checked.

Comment: Thanx @lonesomeday, I tried it, and the first condition works fine, but for some reason the second fails
`chck = $(this).find('input:radio:checked');`
`if (!chck.length) {alert("Please choose an answer");}`
`else {if (chck.val() = CorrectAnswer) {alert("You are correct!");}`
`else {alert("You are wrong!");}}`

Comment: @Ilya `if (chck.val() = CorrectAnswer)` You are using a single `=`.  This is the assignment operator, not the comparison operator. Use `==` instead.