# Know the non selected values in a select form with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know the elements that are not selected inside a `select form`. (This `select` has been created dynamically with a `for loop`).

I know how to know the selected values,

```
$('#bbdd_btn').click(function(){
    $("#select_nodes").each(function() {
        var selected = $(this).children(":selected").val();
        console.log(selected);
    });
});
```

But I want to know the non selected. I've reading some posts and I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048727/jquery-using-to-say-not-selected) but I don't know how to do it correctly. I try this,

```
$('#bbdd_btn').click(function(){
    $("#select_nodes").each(function() {
        var selected = $(this).children(":selected").val();
        console.log(selected);

        var not_selected = $(this).children:not(":selected").val();
        //var no_selected = $(this):not(":selected").val();
        //var no_selected = $(this).children(:not(":selected").val();
        console.log(not_selected);
    });
});
```

Which is the right way to do it?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change your code in this way

```
$('#bbdd_btn').click(function(){
   $("#select_nodes option").each(function() {
      if($(this).is(':selected')){
        console.log(selected);
      }else{
        console.log(not_selected);
      }      
   });
});
```

Comment: But here where is taking the selected and non selected options?

Comment: in "if" statement you can filter selected and non selected option